# Can i config Main App of Pyramid with JWT pyramid-jwt and SessionAuthenticationPolicy

Tags: python, python-2.7, jwt, pyramid

I have a problem when i try to config my app main of pyramid:
Before my config is: (I have authentification within session of pyramid)

```
authn_policy = SessionAuthenticationPolicy()
authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()

# configuration de pyramid : on utilise le données renseignées dans le
# fichier de config (settings), les données d'authentification
config = Configurator(
    settings=settings,
    root_factory=RootFactory,
    authentication_policy=authn_policy,
    authorization_policy=authz_policy,
    session_factory=session_factory,
)
```

then when i try to add JWT configuration it doesn't work because I have already authentication_policy=authn_policy, above :

```
# New configuration of JWT authentification for Pyramid
# Enable JWT authentication.
config.include('pyramid_jwt')
config.set_jwt_authentication_policy('secret')
```

I would like to use the both solutions of authentification, SessionAuthentificationPolicy and pyramid-jwt ?

Error: pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions

Comment: Did you check the docs? There's an example in the documentation that illustrates a similar issue and how to resolve it with `pyramid.config.Configurator.commit()`: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/extconfig.html#using-config-action-in-a-directive

Comment: I found this way https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/configuration/whirlwind_tour.html#resolving-conflicts I don't have error raise but my application doesn't work KO

Comment: First ensure that each method "works" when only one authentication method is configured at a time. Then try to use both. Also provide the full stack trace instead of the just the last error message. Finally it might be helpful to provide a reproducible example in a public repository. For me, two authentication methods is one too many and I've never tried it, so perhaps a more experienced Pyramid developer can provider further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, Pyramid does not support multiple authentication policies out of the box. https://github.com/mozilla-services/pyramid_multiauth might help.